# Get option value of dynamically added options

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, magento

Here the code **which creates options for select tag**, **i wanted the option value on change the option**, i have tried almost everything that i can put in it, but no luck
i can't even see the "selected" attribute in options, i have added the picture of html structure & code. Please share your thoughts on this. Thanks.
Here is the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/pa8e47nx/1/

[image]

```
Product.Config.prototype.loadOptions = function() {
    this.settings.each(function(element){
        element.disabled = false;
        element.options[0] = new Option(this.config.chooseText, '');
        var attributeId = element.id.replace(/[a-z]*/, '');
        var options = this.getAttributeOptions(attributeId);
        if(options) {
            var index = 1;
            for(var i=0;i<options.length;i++){
                options[i].allowedProducts = options[i].products.clone();
                element.options[index] = new Option(this.getOptionLabel(options[i], options[i].price), options[i].id);
                if (typeof options[i].price != 'undefined') {
                    element.options[index].setAttribute('price', options[i].price);
                }
                element.options[index].setAttribute('data-label', options[i].label.toLowerCase());
                element.options[index].config = options[i];
                index++;
            }
        }
        this.reloadOptionLabels(element);
    }.bind(this));
},
```

Comment: Can you please create a jsfiddle for your issue ?

Comment: sure, let me try

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pa8e47nx/1/

Comment: Did you try this? `$('body').on('change', '#attribute125', e => console.log(e.currentTarget.value);});`

Comment: can you please provide Jquery code, i am using magento 1, that using prototype js

Comment: That code have syntax error

Comment: Sorry don't know about prototype.js. This is jQuery code though. I updated your fiddle you can take a look. https://jsfiddle.net/h1d359j6/

Comment: Besides, if you are dynamically creating DOM elements, then for event listening you should you a format like this: `$('body').on('event_name', 'element_selector', custom_function(){})`. This is jQuery format. If you use vanilla JS you can use `addEventListener`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216864/discussion-between-hamendra-sunthwal-and-wahid-masud).

Comment: Can you please check this - https://jsfiddle.net/3e64t80a/

Comment: @PrinceIsNinja , thanks for the response, but you've changed the js which i have added in the js fiddle i've provided

Comment: Can you please explain your problem in detail.