# How to change new version jquery code to old version of code

Tags: javascript, jquery

i wanted to change the below code to compatible with **jquery version 1.4.1**

```
$(document).on("change","select",function(){
      $("option[value=" + this.value + "]", this)
  .attr("selected", true).siblings()
  .removeAttr("selected")
});
```

Comment: What have you tried? what is failing when you try it?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).setValue is not a function

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'destroy' of undefined

Comment: These are the error's came

Comment: Please include the attempted code so we can see what you have, it will be much easier to guide you then.

Comment: 1.4 is at least 12 years old. Why on earth would you need to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The [on](https://api.jquery.com/on/) handler was added in v1.7. Before that, you could use the [live](https://api.jquery.com/live/) handler, which was added in 1.3 and **depreciated** in 1.7.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("select").live("change", function() {  
    console.log('change event ' + this.value)   
  });
});
```

Note you can use the [change](https://api.jquery.com/change/) handler if your dropdown is static content.

http://jsfiddle.net/tg8y6nos/1/

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, but its not working for jquery version 1.4

Comment: Are you creating the select html dynamically? Also can you supply more code

Comment: check this question code, that's the code is responsible for creation of the options https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62632597/get-option-value-of-dynamically-added-options

Comment: Your code is adding the options dynamically. However it's hard to tell how the select html is being generated. Hopefully live handler will do the trick.

Comment: Ok @Greg let me check

Comment: I've updated the answer above, your code should work with the live handler

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'live' of null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216881/discussion-between-greg-and-hamendra-sunthwal).